# Supervisory watchdog to assure UV LEDs are off and stay off during non-use

Tags: power, led, safety, watchdog, uv

I'm designing a circuit consisting of 3 pairs of LEDs. Each pair has one UV-LED and a white LED. The pairs will be turned on consecutively and for about 1 second each. Between each use there will be an arbitrary time frame but the minimum amount of time between each use is at least 5 minutes.

Since I am working with UV LEDs and white LEDs (that contain wavelengths in UV area) I want to design this board in a way to make sure that even if the CPU crashes, or if gamma radiation changes a register on the CPU, that those LEDs are not turned on by accident.

I looked through a few watchdog timer ICs and stumbled over supervisory watchdog ICs that check if power rails are within a certain voltage range, https://www.ti.com/product/TPS386000. I would want to check if those power rails are on for a certain period of time and if they are then safely turned off.

Any suggestions on how to design this safety feature?

Comment: For safety critical applications, you probably want to control and/or limit the durations in hardware. Then, the processor must command the hardware with an *arm-fire* sequence so rogue processing is extremely unlikely to trigger it. You need to explain your situation better to get better answers.

Comment: Thanks! 
I want to use a normal watchdog timer that receives an input from my uC. 
I want to connect the output of the watchdog with a MOSFET that opens the power rail for my LEDs if the uC sends the signal. If the watchdog does not receive a signal anymore, the output of the watchdog shuts down the MOSFET which in turn disconnects the power rail from the UV LEDs.

Comment: OK, if you are set on a system concept, then realize that this is not a design service. Show us an attempt at a circuit design and then ask for advice.

Comment: What if the program or input logic or inputs that activate the LEDs are faulty, but the logic that feeds the watchdog is working fine?   So maybe you enforce a maximum duration on the LEDs themselves.  But then what's the rule for how often they can be re-triggered?   Perhaps you are making this too complicated; what's the distinction between safe and unsafe uses of the UV?  Can you interlock the power with enclosure switches in the traditional way?

Comment: The normal basis for a safety critical circuit is that your design can tolerate one failure - but you must be able to detect all failures. For your micro, you can use a watchdog circuit - but you must be able to test that it works. Then you have the mosfet. You need to be able to test this and have a secondary method to stop the current to the led. That secondary method also needs to be tested.

Comment: I will disconnect the power supply of the whole LED board and add a supervisory watchdog that opens a mosfet switch as long as the Microcontroller is working fine. Then on the next level I use a multichannel switch to turn the rails for the LEDs on and off. The LEDs are then enabled but cannot function yet because they are still connected to a PWM driver that controls the brightness of those LEDs. Even if all switches are on, the microcontroller still needs to adress the PWM driver to start the LEDs.